# Import existing Azure resource groups to terraform state

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-resource-manager

We are migrating from doing Azure deployments via ARM to using Terraform across dev teams. We're looking at ways to migrate the current deployments into TF state, as there are a large number of resource groups across many subscriptions, each with a number of resources. Most existing deployments use monolithic ARM templates (thousands of lines in some cases) with a number of dependencies, so deploying from scratch is not an option at the current time for some teams.

Trying to use tf import 1-by-1 is problematic because each of these resource groups has multiple environments, so with the number of things to move it'll be a huge undertaking. There's also the difficuly that is looking up Azure resource ID's for each one.

To do an import in a more straightforward and batch-like way, we've looked at [terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer) but that has some shortcomings as well. Not all Azure resources are supported, and while we could contribute to the code to add them there seems to be a bigger problem. Terraformer wants to interrogate all deployed resources for the subscription, then filter by what you're asking it to do after. The number of resources deployed seems to overwhelm the program and it starts spitting errors. We've also seen [Az2TF](https://github.com/andyt530/py-az2tf) but that stopped development with the azurerm provider 1.44.

Has anyone done a large tf migration like this that could point us in another direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can store into multiple tfstates
One environnement, one tfstate

```
### Import - ENV1 Prod
terraform import -var-file="environment/prod/env_terraform.tfvars" -state=tfstates/prod/terraform.tfstate azurerm_monitor_autoscale_setting.VMSS_autoscale /subscriptions/XXXX/resourceGroups/my_resourceGroupsPROD/providers/Microsoft.insights/autoscalesettings/my_autoscale
### Import - ENV2 No Prod
terraform import -var-file="environment/nopro/env_terraform.tfvars" -state=tfstates/noprod/terraform.tfstate azurerm_monitor_autoscale_setting.VMSS_autoscale /subscriptions/XXXX/resourceGroups/my_resourceGroupsNOPROD/providers/Microsoft.insights/autoscalesettings/my_autoscale
```

Then, when you apply, you must specify the file

```
### Apply - ENV2 No Prod
terraform apply -var-file="environment/noprod/env_terraform.tfvars" -var="action=charge" -state=tfstates/noprod/terraform.tfstate
```

Comment: Thx for this answer. It worked after I set the state option in "": `terraform import -var-file="environment/prod/env_terraform.tfvars" -state="tfstates/prod/terraform.tfstate" azurerm_monitor_autoscale_setting.VMSS_autoscale /subscriptions/XXXX/resourceGroups/my_resourceGroupsPROD/providers/Microsoft.insights/autoscalesettings/my_autoscale`